# How to calculate two datagridview cells and show the result in third cell as soon as user type?

Tags: c#, winforms

In c# winform for TextBox Text_change event  we see that as soon as we type, we can calculate two textbox and the sum is displayed in another textbox. So can we do the same  textchange event for a data grid view. I already found the code in which two cells are being calculate but after we press the tab button.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{ 
  if (e.RowIndex > -1)
   {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            string valueA = row.Cells[TRP2.Index].Value.ToString();
            string valueB = row.Cells[Quantity.Index].Value.ToString();
            decimal result;
            if (Decimal.TryParse(valueA, out result)
                    && Decimal.TryParse(valueB, out result))
            {
                decimal v1 = Convert.ToDecimal(valueA);
                decimal v2 = Convert.ToDecimal(valueB);
                row.Cells[Total.Index].Value = v1 * v2;
            }
  }
   dg1SalesCalculation();
}
```

Thank in advance.

With regards 
Manoj

Comment: Show some code, that you have tried using the datagridview.

Comment: Use dataGridView1_CellValueChanged event

Comment: Thank u S.Petrosov. But it does not work. Should I change the code?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found this answer long back. and I am posting this code. Before that you should first select your datagridview, in Properties-->Event--> double click on CellValidated. This will generate the event. Now in the code:- first decleare variables followed by the CellValidated code.
  In this I have two columns Rate and Qty and a third one called Amount to store the answer. And here is the code:-

```
string valueTRP;
string valueQTY;
private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex > -1)
    {
            DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            if (row.Cells[Rate.Index].Value.ToString() != "")
            {
                valueTRP = row.Cells[Rate.Index].Value.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                valueTRP = "0";
            }
            if (row.Cells[Qty.Index].Value.ToString() != "")
            {
                valueQTY = row.Cells[Qty.Index].Value.ToString();
            }
           if (Decimal.TryParse(valueTRP, out result) && Decimal.TryParse(valueQTY, out result))
            {
                decimal vTRP = Convert.ToDecimal(valueTRP);
                decimal vQTY = Convert.ToDecimal(valueQTY);
                decimal z = vTRP * vQTY;
                string x = z.ToString("F");
                row.Cells[Amount.Index].Value = x;
            }
    }
}
```